# CakePHP 3 - call object from other helper

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, helper, non-member-functions

I'm actually working on a Helper for CakePHP3 that include BsHelper and then the BsFormHelper.

Actually everything looks good, no problem with Bootstrap formats.

I try now to create a ckEditor instance, but I meet some several problems.

If i try to call my ckEditor like this :

```
$this->BsForm->ckEditor('test')
```

I just have some problems because the function ckEditor is in my BsFormHelper, and load function is in BsHelper. So when i try to access private var to know if i had to load ckEditor i got that issue :

> Error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object 
>   File C:\wamp3\www\wac_lucien\BsHelpersCakePHP3\3.2\plugins\BsHelpers\src\View\Helper\BsFormHelper.php

So in fact I know where is the issue :

In BsFormHelper my fonction looks like :

```
public function ckEditor($fieldName, $options = array(), $ckEditorOptions = array()) {
    $options['type'] = 'textarea';

    $out = $this->input($fieldName, $options);

    // If there is a point in the fieldName
    if (strpos($fieldName, '.') !== false) {
        $nameForReplace = Inflector::camelize(Inflector::slug($fieldName));
    } else {
        $nameForReplace = $this->_modelForm . Inflector::camelize($fieldName);
    }

    $this->Bs->load('ckeditor');

    $this->Bs->loadJS('CKEDITOR.replace("' . $nameForReplace . '", ' . json_encode($ckEditorOptions) . ');', true);
    return $out;
}
```

And in my BsHelper i got :

```
public function load($key) {
    if (!$this->__extensions[$key]['loaded']) {
        foreach ($this->__extensions[$key]['css'] as $css) {
            $this->loadCSS($css);
        }
        foreach ($this->__extensions[$key]['js'] as $js) {
            $this->loadJS($js);
        }
        $this->__extensions[$key]['loaded'] = true;
    }

    return $this->__extensions[$key]['loaded'];
}
```

Values are in declaration like this

```
public $__extensions = array(
    'jasny' => array(
        'css' => array(
            '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/css/jasny-bootstrap.min.css'
        ),
        'js' => array(
            '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js'
        ),
        'loaded' => true
    ),
    'ckeditor' => array(
        'css' => array(),
        'js' => array(
            '//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.8/standard/ckeditor.js'
        ),
        'loaded' => true
    )
);
```

Can someone help me to find out ? It looks like load function called in BsFormHelper can't access privates vars from BsHelper ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cakephp access helper from within another helper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317894/cakephp-access-helper-from-within-another-helper). That question is about cakephp 2 but still valid for cake3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you are just trying to use a helper in another helper

The [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers.html#including-other-helpers) says

> You may wish to use some functionality already existing in another
>   helper. To do so, you can specify helpers you wish to use with a
>   $helpers array, formatted just as you would in a controller:

So in your `BsFormHelper` just do

```
public $helpers = ['Bs'];
```

and you're done

Comment: Thanks ! I just figgure it out ! In fact i met some others troubles with $helpers declaration ... Just need to declare them all in $helpers :D Thanks guy for your time !